# Create child process and kill it after the process is invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I use child process as follows

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var cmd = 'npm install async --save';

    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if(error || stderr){
            console.error(error);
            console.error(stderr);
            console.log("test");
        }


    });
exec.kill();
```

I want that when the process finished kill it,how I can do that?
I try like I put in the post which cause errors...

- how to kill process
- how to veify that this process killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec function returns a ChildProcess object, which has the kill method:

```
var child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if(error || stderr){
        console.error(error);
        console.error(stderr);
        console.log("test");
    }


});

child.kill();
```

It also has the exit event:

```
child.on("exit", function (code, signal) {
  if (code === null && signal === "SIGTERM") {
    console.log("child has been terminated");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks 1+, 2 questions , How should I verify that the process killed? 2. in the child.on what should I put inside and in the variables

Comment: You can verify it using the event. When it occurs it means the process exited (has been killed). The variables code and signal just specify the way it ended. For example if you just kill the process using the kill method, code will be null and signal will contain "SIGTERM".

Comment: I edited the answer. It's just a basic implementation, you can modify it (change signal etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot ,last question how can I get the PID when I execute action?

Comment: Just child.pid. It's all in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html